# Permission to connect to network folder

Tags: networking, file-permissions, user-permissions, redirection, folder-redirection

Small company with 5 users running a domain on SBS 2008R2. PCs are all running Windows 10.

We have had folder redirection enabled for several years and recently one of my users (Sandra) was unable to access her desktop when logging in for the day. Error "... does not have permission to access \NAS\username\Desktop ..."

Everyone else is just fine. Tried using her PC to log in as another user - no problems. Desktop was recreated as it should. Moved to a different PC and logged in as Sandra - surprise! No problem accessing redirected Desktop.

Why would one PC claim a permission error when another PC doesn't?

Frustratedly yours,

Gary

Answer (score 1):

Log into the machine with an account that does work and check your event logs. From my experience, sometimes its a corrupt user profile on that machine. If that is the case, once you log into the machine(The account you log in with has to have admin privileges) and go to C:\Users. From there delete or rename Sandra's profile, logout of the machine and log in as Sandra. That should recreate Sandra's profile. If it doesn't work, then you might have to delete Sandra's profile registry key. Try the above first to see if it works and let us know.